# React Native Animating List of texts

Tags: animation, react-native

I have an array of texts that I want to flash on a blank screen, one after the other with animations. Something like:

```
state = {
  meditations: ["Take a deep breath", "embrace this feeling", "breath 
             deeply", ...]
}
```

I want to show only one string at a time, and animate their opacity. So a string fades in and fades out, then the next string, and so on.

I am new to react native and quite confused about how to go about this. Please, how may I approach this, I have read the docs but still not clear how to.

Below is what I have tried, I modified this from the docs but it shows everything at once. I'm still trying to see how I can make them animate one after the other, showing only one at a time. Thanks for your help in advance.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Animated, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class FadeInView extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0),  // Initial value for opacity: 0
  }
  
  renderMeditations() {
    let { fadeAnim } = this.state;
    return this.props.meditations.map((meditation, index) => {
         Animated.timing(                  // Animate over time
          this.state.fadeAnim,            // The animated value to drive
          {
            toValue: 2,                   // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
            duration: 10000,              // Make it take a while
          }
        ).start(() => {
          this.setState({ fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0) })
        });                        // Starts the animation
    
      return (
        <Animated.Text                // Special animatable View
          key={index}
          style={{
            ...this.props.style,
            opacity: fadeAnim,         // Bind opacity to animated value
          }}
        >
       {meditation}
      </Animated.Text>
      )
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        {this.renderMeditations()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    meditations: ["Take a deep breath", "Calm down", "Relax", "Tell yourself all will be fine"]
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <FadeInView meditations={this.state.meditations} style={{fontSize: 28, textAlign: 'center', margin: 10}} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Show some code that shows you have tried using at least the base API for animations. Of which you clearly didnt read : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html or this library if you dont understand the API : https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable

Comment: Hi @WilomGfx I have added the code I was playing around with. I actually did read the base API. may be I didn't ask the question well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map function executes all at once so basically you are rendering/returning all 3 items at the same time. I understand that your issue is that the animation is working tho.

If what you want is to show one text, then the other and so on I suggest iterating the index of your text array instead of using the map function.

Something like:

1. Execute Animation
2. Increase Index
3. Index = 0 if you are at the end of the array.

In a loop. Check setInterval, it might help you.

Comment: Thanks very much for your idea, but please can you show by example what you mean. thanks

Comment: @AwaDesmoline Excellent. Please consider accepting the answer so it does not go unsolved.

Answer (score 6):

After much toil with this, I was able to solve it with `react-native-animatable` like so:

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Animated
} from "react-native";


import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';


class VideoScreen extends React.Component {

  state = {
    meditations: ["Take a deep breath", "embrace this feeling", "breath 
         deeply"],
    index: 0
  };

  render() {
    const { meditations, index } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Animatable.Text
          key={index}
          animation={'fadeIn'}
          iterationCount={2}
          direction="alternate"
          duration={2000}
          onAnimationEnd={() => {
            if (this.state.index < this.state.meditations.length - 1) {
              this.setState({ index: this.state.index + 1});
            }
          }}
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            left: 0, right: 0,
            bottom: 40
          }}>
          {meditations[index]}
        </Animatable.Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default VideoScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the function components:-

we can use the above-metioned solutions. I am writing a function hopefully it will help you display a looping text with the animation

We will use this package for the animation https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable.

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';

const UserMessage = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const meditations = [
    'Take a deep breath',
    'embrace this feeling',
    'breath deeply',
   ];
return (
<Animatable.Text
  key={index}
  animation={'fadeIn'}
  iterationCount={2}
  direction="alternate"
  duration={2000}
  onAnimationEnd={() => {
    if (index < meditations.length - 1) {
      setIndex(index + 1);
    } else {
      setIndex(0);
    }
  }}
  style={styles.messageStyle}>
  {meditations[index]}
</Animatable.Text>
);
};

export default UserMessage;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 messageStyle: {
textAlign: 'center',
fontSize: 18,
fontWeight: '500',
width: '80%',
color: '#1C1C1C',
marginBottom: 20,
minHeight: 50,
alignSelf: 'center',
},
});
```